# VS 2015 RC - Xaml designer won't load when trying to create windows 10 universal apps in Windows 8

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, visual-studio-2015

I've started working on Windows 10 IoT apps, and I'm baffled by the following issue XAML designer won't load when trying to create Windows 10 universal apps in Windows 8 VS 2015 RC. Upon comparing the blank project XAML for Windows 8 applications to the new blank project XAMLfor windows, they appear to be identical.

Except when I double click my Windows 10 Mainpage.xmal I only see the code and the show designer button doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is "Enable XAML Designer" option unchecked? In Tools-> Options-> XAML Designer

Comment: Thank you Bells for the response, yes the Enable XAML Designer is checked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is expected on Windows 8. Windows 10 is required for the designer since the designer uses the local OS to render the design canvas. Since Windows 10 apps don't run on Windows 8 they can't render in the designer. Since Windows 8 apps do run on Windows 8 they will render in the designer.

Navit discusses OS support for Universal Windows development about 7 minutes in to his Build session [Developing Universal Windows Apps in Visual Studio 2015](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-650)